# jqGrid - saveRow doesn't work with custom form - no HTTP POST

Tags: html, ajax, json, jsp, jqgrid

I have following jqGrid with a custom form:

```
jQuery("#list_klanten").jqGrid({
    url:'data/relations_select.jsp',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['ID','Klantcode','EAN','Naam','Street','Postal','City','Country','Phone','Status','Cust','Supp','VAT','Language','Currency','','Relationtype','Legal','MotherC','Repr.','Region','Email','Websiote','Faxnr'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:50,editable:false,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'relation_code',index:'relation_code', width:150,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'ean_code',index:'ean_code', width:150,editable:true,hidden:true,editoptions:{size:25}}, 
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:250,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'streetname',index:'streetname', width:300,editable:true,sortable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'postal_code',index:'postal_code', width:75,editable:true,sortable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'city',index:'city', width:200,editable:true,sortable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'country',index:'country', width:150,editable:true,sortable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'telephone_nr',index:'telephone_nr', width:150,editable:true,hidden:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'relation_status',index:'relation_status', width:150,editable:true,hidden:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'customer_flag',index:'customer_flag', width:100,editable:false,search:false,hidden:false,formatter:'checkbox',align:'center',editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'supplier_flag',index:'supplier_flag', width:100,editable:false,search:false,hidden:false,formatter:'checkbox',align:'center',editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'vat_nr',index:'vat_nr', width:150,editable:true,hidden:false,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'language',index:'language', width:150,editable:true,hidden:false,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'currency_code',index:'currency_code', width:150,editable:true,hidden:false,editoptions:{size:25}},
        {name:'arrow',index:'arrow', width:50,editable:false,search:false,formatter:linkFormatter},
    ],
    width:1100,
    height:600,
    rowNum:20,
    editurl:'data/relations_edit.jsp',
    pager: '#pager_klanten',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption:"Klanten",
    grouping: true,
    groupingView : {
        groupField : ['currency_code'],
        groupColumnShow : [true],
        groupText : ['<b>{0}</b>'],
        groupCollapse : false,
        groupOrder: ['asc'],
        groupSummary : [true],
        groupDataSorted : false
    },
    onSelectRow: function(){
        var gsr = jQuery("#list_klanten").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
        if(gsr){
            jQuery("#list_klanten").jqGrid('GridToForm',gsr,"#relation_detail");
        } else {
            alert("Please select Row")
        }
    },
});
jQuery("#list_klanten").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager_klanten',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false},{height:400,reloadAfterSubmit:true,closeAfterEdit:true,url:'data/relations_edit.jsp'},{height:400,reloadAfterSubmit:true,closeAfterAdd:true,url:'data/relations_edit.jsp'});
```

When a row is selected, a form is filled with the selected values so that the user can edit a record in this form.
When clicked on save, following code is executed :

```
jQuery("#savedata").click(function(){
        var rowid = jQuery("#row_id").val();
        jQuery("#list_klanten").jqGrid('FormToGrid',rowid,'#relation_detail');
        jQuery("#list_klanten").saveRow(rowid,null,'data/relations_edit.jsp');
});
```

I see the edited values (temporarily) in the grid itself but the actual 'save' doesn't work.
When I look in FireBug I don't see the data/relations_edit.jsp being called...?
There are also no errors or warnings, so just nothing is happening.
What am I missing here?

The standard edit option - editing withing the modal pop-up - works just fine...

Thanks a lot !

Robrecht

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the HTTP POST not being done :
jqGrid requires that the grid is in editmode.

I had to add

```
jQuery("#list_klanten").editRow(rowid);
```

to my code

but...

When I edit some fields in my custom form, those fields are updated in the grid, but not posted. It seems that the items in my custom form aren't posted to the editurl...

After some research I found that you have to make a custom ajax call to post all the edited values :

```
var data = $('#relation_detail').serialize();
$.post('data/relations_edit.jsp', data);
```

If someone has a better solution I'd be happy to know about it, but this works fine fore me at the moment.

Robrecht